# Difficulty with haven package Reading SPSS data in R

Tags: r, spss, r-haven

I am trying to use the haven package to read spss data and am getting the following error:

> Error in df_parse_sav_file(spec, encoding, user_na, cols_skip, n_max, 
>   :    Failed to parse ~FilePath/Dataset: The file's timestamp string is
>   invalid.

I have tried to update the package and restart my R session but am still having difficulty.

Comment: For reading SPSS data, you can also use `foreign` R package.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been reported widely:

You can try reverting to 1.1.0, which seemed to fix the issue for a lot of people.

```
remove.packages("haven")
devtools::install_version("haven", version = "1.1.0", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Comment: In my case, the error remains after doing this.

Comment: Likewise I was not able to resolve the issue after reverting to 1.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Although it seems silly, try to save the document with another name before trying to load it with haven. In my case this trick has worked smoothly.